# Create function for converting time zones in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2

Here is my code and it's working perfect

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[udf_ConvertfromUTCtoCET]
    (@UTCDate AS DATETIME2(7))
RETURNS DATETIME2(7)
AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @DstStart datetime2(7)
    DECLARE @DstEnd datetime2(7)
    DECLARE @CetDate datetime2(7)

    SELECT 
        @DstStart = DATEADD(hour, 1,DATEADD(day, DATEDIFF(day, 0, '31/Mar' + CAST(YEAR(@UTCDate) AS varchar)) - 
        (DATEDIFF(day, 6, '31/Mar' + CAST(YEAR(@UTCDate) AS varchar)) % 7), 0)),
        @DstEnd = DATEADD(hour, 1,DATEADD(day, DATEDIFF(day, 0, '31/Oct' + CAST(YEAR(@UTCDate) AS varchar)) - 
        (DATEDIFF(day, 6, '31/Oct' + CAST(YEAR(@UTCDate) AS varchar)) % 7), 0))

    SELECT 
       @CetDate = CASE 
                     WHEN @UTCDate <= @DstEnd AND @UTCDate >= @DstStart
                       THEN DATEADD(hour, +2, @UTCDate)
                       ELSE DATEADD(hour, +1, @UTCDate) 
                  END

    RETURN @CetDate
END


select 
    [DateTime] AS UTC,
    [dbo].[udf_ConvertfromUTCtoCET] ([DateTime]) AS CET 
from 
    WarehouseMgmt.DimTime
```

Now I would like to put another parameter in the function something like

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[udf_ConvertfromUTCtoCET] 
   (@UTCDate AS DATETIME2(7), @TimeZone nvarchar(5))
```

I will have not just from UTC to CET, but if I want I will put in `@TimeZone` parameter for example 'BST' (british summer time ) or some other time zone and my UTC time will be converted in that zone

Comment: To give you an idea of the complexity of the problem. There is a database of world time zones at http://www.iana.org/time-zones The list of time zones change quite often, the rules for switching between summer and winter times change within the same zone. For example, Perth does not have daylight saving since 2009 (and had it only for 3 summers 2006-7 2007-8 and 2008-9). So, to implement your function you should "simply" take the database from IANA, store it in your database and use in your function. Don't forget to update it regularly as well.

Comment: no i don't want all time zones , just few of them, like UTC,CET,BST,and some others. How i can just add a parameter and switch between time zone ?

Comment: As far as I know, SQL Server doesn't have a built-in function for it. So, you'll have to take that IANA database and extract information about few timezones from it. Of course, you can hard-code the rules for them as you did for CET and don't bother about past and future dates. It will work fine until the government decides to make changes.